# ESAPI for email address "blabla@example.com"

Tags: rest, email-validation, esapi

I saw some related questions. But I was not getting what exactly I was looking for. Sorry, if this turns out to be a silly request. Hopefully, I am having this specific query:

So I am trying to make a ReST API with MySQL database.
I am trying to read data from a table which is basically pulling out the valid email addresses of the users. 
The output is going to be displayed on a HTML page.

```
temp = blabla@example.com
temp = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(temp);
temp = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(temp);
```

OUTPUT: `temp = blabla&#64;gmail.com`

How can I avoid this from happening? and get blabla@email.com

I think the behavior here is as expected. But I just wanted to know if there is a work around other can Conditional Handling (if..else)
Also, what if someone can point me to the reasoning behind some of design choices for ESAPI. I t should be interesting read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:

If you can *truly* trust what's coming from your database, you don't need to perform canonicalize.  If you *know* your data isn't going to be used by a browser, don't encode for HTML.  If however you *suspect* your data will be used by a browser, encode it, have the caller deal with the results.  If that's deemed unacceptable, expose an "unsafe" version of your webservice, one whose URL will explicitly use warning words to flag as "potentially malicious," forcing your caller to be aware that they're engaging in unsafe activity.

LONG ANSWER:

Well first, according to your use-case, you're essentially providing data to a calling client.  My first instinct upon reading your question is that I don't think you're comfortable with your data contexts.

So, typically you're going to see a call to `canonicalize()` when you need safe data to perform validation against.  So, the first questions to ask are these:

q1:  Can I trust the data coming from my database?

Guidelines for q1:  If the data is appropriately validated and neutralized, say by using a call to `ESAPI.validator().getValidInput( args );` by the process that stores the data, then the application will store a safe email string into the database.  If you can provably trust your input data at this point, it should be completely safe for you to *not* canonicalize your output as you're doing here.

If however, you **cannot** trust the data at this point, then you're in a scenario where before you pass along data to a downstream system, you'll need to validate it.  A call to `ESAPI.validator().getValidInput( args );` will BOTH canonicalize the input and ensure that its a valid email address.  However this comes with the baggage that your caller is going to have to properly transform the neutralized input, which according to your question is what you want to avoid.

If you want to send safe data downstream, and you cannot defensibly trust your data source, you have no choice but to send safe data to your caller and have them work with it on their end--except perhaps to expose an unsafe method, which I will discuss shortly.

q2:  Will browsers be used to consume my data?

Guidelines for q2:  the `encoder.encodeForHTML()` method is designed to neutralize *browser* interpretation.  Since you're talking about RESTful web services, I don't understand why you think you need to use it, because a browser should correctly interpret `blabla&#64;gmail.com` to the correct canonical form--unless perhaps its being correctly trapped as a data element, such as in a dropdown box. But this is something I'm guessing you have NO control over?

As you can now tell, there are no fast answers to questions like this.  You have to have some idea of how the data will be used by your caller.  Since you have the possibility of having your data treated correctly as data by the browser, and the possibility of the data treated as code, you might be forced to offer a "safe" and "unsafe" call to retrieve your data, assuming that you have no control over how the client uses your service.  That puts you in a bad spot, because a lazy caller might simply only ever use the unsafe version.  When this happens in my industry, I'll usually make it so that the URL to call for an unsafe function looks something like `mywebservice.com/unSafeNonPCICompliantMethod` or something similar, so that you force your caller to explicitly accept the risk.  If its being used in the correct context on the browser... the unsafe method might actually be safe.  You just won't know.

Comment: using HTML encoded version of email address is throwing **Illegal semicolon, not in group in string**. any suggestions on this?

Comment: could not paste complete code here: '        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
 
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(toAddress)) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());'

Comment: @DecKno I can't unit test that, but it seems to me that you're building an email message, when the use case for encodeForHTML is to display the content to the user in a browser.

Comment: In this case, you will want to have canonicalized the user input, and validated it as a legit email address.  HTML (or other kinds of) encoding are literally done immediately before you display content to a user.

Comment: thank you for the info. i took HTML as a solution to mitigate CRLF for email address which worked. But as you mentioned, is there any alternate way to check without modifying email address?

Comment: @DecKno I've usually used something like `String addy = String.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");`

Comment: Actually, I just tested `Validator.isValidInput("test", "jeff.williams@aspectsecurity.com\n\r", "Email", 100, false)` in ESAPI, and it rejects the email.  So it's up to you how you want to handle it.